# Xbox 360 Controller connects as third player and doesn't work

Tags: windows-8.1, xbox360, game-controller

My 360 controller connects to the usb wireless receiver no problem, but it always joins as 3rd player.  My games all see it as Xinput controller 3 (if they see it at all) but oddly don't see the other two invisible controllers.  I can't use it for any single player gaming and I have no idea why it's doing this.

I've removed all relevant devices that I can find (I even used devmgr_show_nonpresent_device to make sure I got them all) from Device Manager and I've rebooted several times and yelled loudly at it.  The controller always connects as third and then nothing can find it.

Has anyone seen anything like this and maybe have an idea of what else to try?  I've been trying to find a tool that would allow me to see what else is using XInput ports, but can't find anything besides possible relevant API calls I could try if I wanted to set up a dev environment on my gaming machine.....

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oh, yeahI'm in Windows 8.1

Comment: Is this a legit question on this site?

Comment: "Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's 100% free, no registration required."

Seemed appropriate to me